# Load Balancing Code Modification - Eucalyptus Query

Tags: eucalyptus

I am working on a Cloud Project.

I want to modify the Eucalyptus code for load balancing in the cloud. I have the source code configured with Eclipse. I want to know the dependent files of load balancer in the source code and I need to change them to add a dynamic load balancer in Eucalyptus. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding the ELB is actively discussed and should appear in Eucalyptus soon. TO the original question, if you want to write your own version of ELB, you will need to modify Eucalyptus extensively, starting from the API (do you want to use AWS version? Implement your own one?), going to get the real work done.  It may be easier to hang out on #eucalyptus-devel (freenode) and start asking questions there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable answer if i will have further questions i will ask you personally.